# How to design a nice looking chapter title and page

Tags: header-footer, positioning, numbering, chapters, report

I want to create something like the images I have below:

[image: this]

( I couldn't draw well the chapter number and its font)

and

[image: this]

( I couldn't draw well the page number)

--------------UPDATE According to Gonzalo Medina answer---------------------

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report} 

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} %to use  _ and ^
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{wrapfig} % for wrapping graphics with text
\usepackage{float} % for images
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,top=2.5cm,right=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, amsmath, lettrine,amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,verbatim}
\usepackage{rotating,appendix}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{underscore} %in order to use __
\usepackage{hyperref} % to make hyperlinks

 %----------------------------for changing the chapter format-------------------
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\Huge\scshape}
  {\filleft\tikz\node[fill=green!50!black!10,rectangle,rounded corners=6pt] (chap) {\chaptertitlename};}
  {0ex}
  {\colorbox{green!50!black!10}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\vskip1ex#1\vskip1ex}}}



%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------






\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\newcommand{\EN}[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}} %in order to write english as \EN{Some words in English}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}} %to remove numbering the page from table of contents (ToC)
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}


\chapter*{Preface}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\indent some text

\chapter {Chapter 1}

\textbf {\LARGE Intro}

\setcounter{page}{1}

\section {History}

\indent     Some text ggttg


\section {Another}

\indent    some text



\chapter {Chapter 2}

\textbf {\LARGE Two}
\section {History2}

\indent     text
\end{document}
```

Using the above code i receive [image: this image]

I want [image: that image]

Also,for the second layout ,almost the same.It shows "1:Chapter 1" instead of "1:Intro".
All i want is at every page (except from the first page of each chapter) to show the page number and the title of that chapter

Comment: I don't understand. You say you want to remove the chapter numbering and yet your drawings are showing the chapter number? Do you want the chapter number or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one possibility using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package: according to comments, the chapter number had to be removed. Also, there's no need to use the redefinition for `\@makechapterhead`; all formatting aspects can be modified/controlled in an easier way using `\titleformat`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\Huge\scshape}
  {\filleft\tikz\node[fill=green!50!black!10,rectangle,rounded corners=6pt] (chap) {\chaptertitlename};}
  {0ex}
  {\colorbox{green!50!black!10}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\vskip1ex#1\vskip1ex}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A Test Chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the second layout, you can do something like the following (I should mention that having the page number in the chapter heading seems a little strange):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\Large\scshape}
  {}{0ex}
  {\colorbox{green!50!black!10}{\colorbox{green!50!black!20}{\parbox{1cm}{\thepage}}\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-1cm\relax}{\filcenter\vskip1ex\chaptername~\thechapter: #1\vskip1ex}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A Test Chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

After comments added to the original question, I think that now I know what was requested: the following example shows a modification of the formatting for chapter headings and also a modification to the headers achieved with the help of the fancyhdr package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text for the example

 %----------------------------for changing the chapter format-------------------
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\LARGE\scshape\bfseries}
  {\filleft\tikz\node[fill=green!50!black!10,rectangle,rounded corners=6pt] (chap) {\chaptertitlename~\thechapter};}
  {0ex}
  {\colorbox{green!50!black!10}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\vskip1ex#1\vskip1ex}}}

 %----------------------------for changing the header-------------------
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\colorbox{green!50!black!10}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\colorbox{green!50!black!40}{\thepage:} \leftmark}}}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{24pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{% 
  \markboth{#1}{}} 

\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter {Intro}
\section {Another}
\lipsum[1-15]
\chapter {Two}
\section {History2}
\lipsum[1-15]

\end{document}
```

Comment: :Ok,that's good.At the above,i want Chapter 1 to be in the same font as the"A Test Chapter".The line i draw is just a kind of frame.If i can add this kind of line (semi cycle) it will be perfect.If not,i want a frame.

Comment: Gonzalo Medina:At the second draw the number is the page number.The line is just a frame (as the previously).

Comment: @George I updated my answer. Is it something like that what you want for the first layout? For the second one I still have a doubt; the page number goes framed and to the left and the heading goes centered or flushed right?

Comment: :Thanks for the help.I also updated because your code doesn't work good.From the first layout i just want to fill the frame with the same color.As for the second , the page number goes framed and the heading either center or left or right.

Comment: @George using my code you don't need to use that redefinition of `\@makechapterhead`; just use the modifications built with `titlesec`.

Comment: @George answer updated; something like that? (remember to delete the lines redefining `\@makechapterhead` from your code since they are no longer necessary and will conflict with the layout defined with titlesec).

Comment: MedinaL:If i use [T1]{fontenc} it gives me errors " command \nobreakspace unavailable in encoding T1".If i omit [T1]{fontenc} it gives me the "Chapter 1" inside the colored frame instead of the "A test chapter" and "1" instead of "chapter 1"(all these with omitting the part of code for the number of chapter).

Comment: :Also,what about the second layout?Thanks!

Comment: @George sorry, but that error with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is from elsewhere in *your* code not mine; my code doesn't use `\nobreakspace`, and I can't guess what are you doing. If you want, add to your question a minimal document showing your current settings; otherwise, we will waste valuable time redoing code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5863/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-george)

Comment: @George I updated my answer. As you can see, there's no need to use that redefinition for `\@makechapterhead`; all modifications (including suppressing the chapter number) can be done using the `\titleformat` command. You can safely delete that conflicting redefinition and I can show you how to achieve what you want in an easier way using `\titleformat`.

Comment: :I updated my code,please check what i say and for the second layout.Thank you

Comment: @George I finally think that I understand what you were trying to achieve; I updated my answer with some new code. Please process the example code exactly as it is and let me know if that is what you wanted, or if, at least, its close to what you have in mind so we can then do some adjustments.

Comment: :First of all thank you very much for your help!2 details though.1) if i have "\chapter {\textbf {\LARGE Intro}}",then this bold "Intro" appears at every page (due to the headers layout).Can i do sth? and 2) can i have the page number in a box?like the one you did in your previous answer,in the image above. –

Comment: @George I updated my answer. It's not convenient to use `\LARGE` and `\textbf` directly in the argument of `\chapter`; I made the necessary changes inside `\titleformat`. The page number is bow also inside a colored box.

Comment: :Sorry to disturb,but i am encountering a problem with the title in pages when using minipage.Instead of showing the title "Chapter 3:History" it shows "C  3:H ".Is there any solution to this?

Comment: @George no problem at all! However, as you might suspect, without seeing your code I cannot provide effective help. I think that a fresh question in the form of a [follow-up question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117) is the best way to go here. Please include a minimal complete document with your current settings (relevant to the problem mentioned) and allowing us to reproduce the problem; you can link to this question to provide the background.

Comment: :I really can't include a minimal example because i have 50 pages of document and the problem lies only to 2 pages which include "minimize".But,i saw and one other page i have that has "minimize" also,but has exactly the same layout as the others.Anyway,it's ok,i just came in contact with you maybe you had an idea.Ok,thank you.